# How can I force safari to enable my website javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

Recently I've got feedbacks from collegues and friends that some features of a website of mine doesn't work on Apple devices. With some research, I found out that Safari blocks javascript.

How can I force it?

More specifically, javascript is needed to toggle between light mode and dark mode and italian and english.

Comment: I recommend you to find alternative ways to do it and reconsider your question. What's the point of this feature if you can just force it to run?

Comment: I did some research but found out only how to solve the problem user side (enable javascript on the device), but now to solve the problem dev side.
But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is on the clients side. Some browsers block JS by themselves, others do this due to user-defined settings, e.g. for security reasons.

**You cannot force a browser to use JS.** What you can do instead is build a fallback that works when JS is disabled.

In your case you could set the light/dark mode or the language with a PHP-GET variable in the URL and process that on the server side.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint Luca! Maybe in my research I was simply using the wrong keywords and you helped me a lot

Comment: No problem rx4storm! Don't forget to mark this as resolved

Answer (score 0):

At least I solved it: I used a package to recognize the userAgent (https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect) and then I transform my code to no longer depend on JS, only on safari.

Hope that this can help somebody else!

*(I'm still trying to figure out how to mark this has resolved)*

Comment: Next to Luca's answer, click the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons. That'll mark this as resolved.